# Vbscript to delete files with special characters in their name

Tags: vbscript, symbols, delete-file

I have found how to delete files using VBScript, but for certain filenames that include special characters.

For example: I have a Game (The Sims 3) i have set up to install, then update itself.
I want to use a newer shortcut that comes with the update called "TS3W" as it automatically loads your latest expansions, which saves me from using multiple shortcuts. I have already made a script to create that shortcut, but I cannot delete the old shortcut as it is called 'The Sims 3™'.

The '™' Symbol is not recognized by Vbscript and therefore cannot find the file to delete.

Is there any way I can delete such files using a script of some kind?

Comment: VBScript doesn't have any problem at all handling files with a `™` in their name. Please show your code.

Comment: My Mistake, i was using a batch file. Going to try using VbSCript instead. If you have a script for this you could share it could save me a bit of trouble, thanks anyway - and sorry for the stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBScript you'd do something like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
filename = "C:\path\to\The Sims 3™.lnk"
If fso.FileExists(filename) Then fso.DeleteFile filename, True
```

You should be able to make this work in batch as well, though. Try setting the codepage to 1251 in your script:

```
@echo off
chcp 1251 >nul
del /q "C:\path\to\The Sims 3™.lnk"
```